# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't detect any .net SDKs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2019 on my computer suddenly stopped detecting any dotnet SDKs despite the fact that they are installed. I even reinstalled .Net 5 SDK, but still no dice. Running the command dotnet --list-sdks doesn't yield any results. I also tried to link a path to a folder dotnet, but that didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: Try Visual Studio Installer -> More -> Repair.

Comment: I tried that too, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Would help if you updated the question with all your trials.

Comment: In Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features check if are listed the "Microsoft .Net Core SDK x.y.z".

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Properties -> Environment variables -> System Variables -> and then edit Path.

Check if the Path contains: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.

Also make sure that, if the Path contains  'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet', it is below 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'

Restart

[image]